# How do i smoothen out the curve in my plot?

Tags: r, smoothing, curve

I have these plots, and I would like the curve to be smoother. How can I add that to my code? Thank you!

```
plot(PA_Spe_accum, ci = 1.96, ci.type = "bar", las=1, col = "green3", lty = 1, lwd=2, ci.col = "green3", ci.lty = 1, xlim=c(0,60), ylim=c(0,70))
plot(PA_Spe2_accum, add = TRUE, ci = 1.96, ci.type = 'bar', lwd=2, col = 'royalblue4', lty = 1, ci.col = 'royalblue4', ci.lty = 1)
```

I tried with lowess, but I am not sure how to write it into my code.

Answer (score 1):

Appears,`PA_Spe_accum` and `PA_Spe2_accum` are lists instead of numeric vectors, which is causing the error. You can try converting them to numeric vectors before using the loess function. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve the desired smoothing.

```
PA_Spe_accum_vec <- unlist(PA_Spe_accum)
PA_Spe2_accum_vec <- unlist(PA_Spe2_accum)
smooth_PA_Spe_accum <- loess(PA_Spe_accum_vec ~ seq_along(PA_Spe_accum_vec))
smooth_PA_Spe2_accum <- loess(PA_Spe2_accum_vec ~ seq_along(PA_Spe2_accum_vec))

smoothed_PA_Spe_accum <- predict(smooth_PA_Spe_accum)
smoothed_PA_Spe2_accum <- predict(smooth_PA_Spe2_accum)
plot(smoothed_PA_Spe_accum, ci = 1.96, ci.type = "bar", las=1, col = "green3", lty = 1, lwd=2, ci.col = "green3", ci.lty = 1, xlim=c(0,60), ylim=c(0,70))
lines(smoothed_PA_Spe2_accum, lwd=2, col = 'royalblue4', add = TRUE)
```

please do let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you! It gives me this error:                                                                                           Error in model.frame.default(formula = PA_Spe_accum ~ seq_along(PA_Spe_accum)) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'PA_Spe_accum'                                                                                 I tried to use the unlist() function on x, but it doesn't work. What else could I do?